# Understanding the role of UID in a Spark MLLib Transformer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using Apache Spark with Scala to create an ML Pipeline. One of the Transformers I have in my pipeline does a costly `join` operation early on in the process. Since I have a lot of features in my `ParamGrid` this means that the program has to hold this enormous, joined `DataFrame` in memory while it optimizes over each feature in the grid.

To try and solve this problem I created a custom `Transformer` that caches this large, intermediate `DataFrame` by writing it to a parquet in S3 and returning a DataFrame that is read from the parquet. This worked well and increased the speed of the model *until* I added features to the `ParamGrid` that are staged before the caching stage. When I write the parquet to S3 I use a path that is determined by:

```
class Cacher(override val uid: String) extends Transformer {

  // the cachePath variable determines the path within the S3 bucket
  lazy val cachePath = Identifiable.randomUID(uid + "transformer-cache")

  // ...
```

I think I am misunderstanding how `uid` is working...my belief was that whenever Spark optimized over the `ParamGrid`, it took whatever classes were staged at that point in the pipeline, created new instances of them, and gave them new, unique `uid`s to keep track of them. I suspect that the caching is going awry because Spark is not giving a unique `uid` to the new `Transformer` instances it creates which means that the cached parquet is being continually overwritten whenever a new instance of the cache `Transformer` is created. Can anybody give any pointers on how to generate unique, random `uid`s for each instance of a stage that the pipeline creates?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step by step:

- `uid` is required by the `Identifiable` trait (`Transformer` extends `PipelineStage` which extends `Params` which extends `Identifiable`).
- According to the `Identifiable` docs [`uid` is](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/Identifiable.scala#L37):

  > An immutable unique ID for the object and **its derivatives**.
- In general:

  - `Params` are mutable. Setting parameters returns `this` and doesn't affect `uid`.

    ```scala
    import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder

    val enc = new OneHotEncoder()
    val enc_  = enc.setInputCol("foo")

    enc == enc_
    ```

    ```
    Boolean = true
    ```

    ```scala
    enc.uid == enc_.uid
    ```

    ```
    Boolean = true
    ```
  - `copying` `Params` creates a new instance but keeps the same `uid` (see emphasized part of the quote from the previous point).

    ```scala
    val encCopy = enc.copy(new org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap())

    encCopy == enc
    ```

    ```
    Boolean = false
    ```

    ```scala
    encCopy.uid == enc.uid
    ```

    ```
    Boolean = true
    ```
- You could try to override [`copy` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Transformer.scala#L125) to avoid [copying parent `uid`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f830bb9170f6b853565d9dd30ca7418b93a54fe3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L716) but it seems to be in conflict with the whole idea behind making `Params` `Identifiable`.

Possible solutions:

- Don't use transformer `uid` at all or make path dependent on the current set of parameters.
- Don't write cache files manually and use built-in caching mechanism (`Dataset.persist`). It not only resolves the issue at hand but also addresses a hidden issue which is releasing resources on exit.